The SAML response signature failed to verify from SAML Response
We're using Azure B2C custom policy for SAML Sp-Initiated SSO. Created and uploaded certificate through Microsoft Document guide. We've shared certificate value from <X509Certificate> tag mentioned in metadata url as per this document. Uploaded certificate at the client's SSO configuration.
Testing with the SAML response gives me correct data as shown in below signature.

But client is using the ComponentSpace library and var mySSOResult = await _samlServiceProvider.ReceiveSsoAsync(); function which throws below error can we're stuck at this point.

ComponentSpace.Saml2.Exceptions.SamlSignatureException: The SAML response signature failed to verify.    at ComponentSpace.Saml2.SamlServiceProvider.VerifySamlResponseSignatureAsync(XmlElement samlResponseElement)    at ComponentSpace.Saml2.SamlServiceProvider.ProcessSamlResponseAsync(XmlElement samlResponseElement, String relayState)    at ComponentSpace.Saml2.SamlServiceProvider.ReceiveSsoAsync()    at Dekra.AdaptivePlatform.Web.Areas.App.Controllers.SamlController.AssertionConsumerService(String tenantId) in /agent/_work/1/s/src/Dekra.AdaptivePlatform.Web.Mvc/Areas/App/Controllers/SamlController.cs:line 264    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Logged|12_1(ControllerActionInvoker invoker)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)

Thanks in advance.

Looks like your application is not using the correct certificate to validate the signature from the IdP (B2C).
Check you saved the .cer or .pem to the path referenced in code or configuration, and that it is accessible by the application.
Here's how the token signing public key is usually loaded from file in ComponentSpace.
You should specify the file path in the ComponentSpace config:
<PartnerCertificates>

 <Certificate FileName="Certificates\idp.cer"/>

</PartnerCertificates>

Your saved certificate should also start with -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- on the first line, and -----END CERTIFICATE----- on the last line, with a long base64 encoded string in between.

Actual issue was the way it was exported. Thank you for your help.
